# Apache internal server error page

Tags: apache

How can I configure Apache so that it does not serve the default 500 Internal Server Error page?
Additionally, I do not want a custom one.
I just want any error returned to be printed

Thanks

Comment: I don't think you do want it to just print any errors - that's a great way to leak information

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this for the first part of your question :
http://www.404-error-page.com/404-create-a-custom-404-error-page-with-htaccess.shtml